# Android - running a method periodically using Handler and postDelayed

Tags: java, android

i'm writing simple `spalshScreen` for my application. i want to use `Handler()` and `postDelayed` with that. but in any topics of this site i get this help for use:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do something after 100ms
                Toast.makeText(c, "check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
            }
        }, 1500);
```

but i get this error in `Intllij` IDEA:

[image]

Comment: Just for the future: Remember to add a tag for the language you are using to the question. Without it the syntax highlighting will not work properly. I already added it to your question this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong `Handler`! Look at the top of your Java file, you are going to find something like this:

```
import java.util.logging.Handler;
```

Replace it with this:

```
import android.os.Handler;
```

The `Handler` from the package `android.os` is the one you want. The other one from `java.util.logging` is something completely different and as you already noticed is also an abstract class.

I hope I could help you and if you have any further questions please feel free to ask!